# unit testing $watch of a directive that requires itself

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

I am having some trouble unit testing the watch method of my directive.  The directive requires the its own direcitive so  **ctrl**  houses one main method updateHeight

In my controller I have one method

```
 this.updateHeight = function (clientHeight) {
    $rootScope.haGlobalAlerts.clientHeight = clientHeight;
};
```

Inside of my link function I am calling this

```
 ctrl.updateHeight(el.clientHeight);
```

I have a $watch method that looks for changes

```
  $scope.$watch(function () {
    return el.clientHeight;
  },
    function (newHeight, oldHeight) {
        if (first || (newHeight !== oldHeight)) {
           first = false;
           ctrl.updateHeight(newHeight);
         }
    });
```

Identifying how to test and mock a change is really confusing me.  In my directive I created scope like so ....

```
 html = angular.element("<div global alerts> </div>")
 element = $compile(html)($rootScope);

 $rootScope = $rootScope.$new()

 // added this to get update height

 controller = element.controller('GlobalAlerts')

 //setting controller gives me access to controller.updateHeight().

 scope = element.scope();
```

**scope**  does not have access to this.   I am not sure how to make a call to it.

If I call

```
controller.updateHeight() //It is not changing the value.
```

In my test I have **$apply** called on the scope

scope.$apply()

Here is my complete test

```
 it("should update client Height", function () {

        expect(element[0].clientHeight).to.equal(0);
        var newHeight = 20;
        controller.updateHeight(newHeight);
        scope.$apply();
        expect(element[0].clientHeight).to.equal(20);
    });
```

Comment: show the full code please. method updateHeight belongs to ctrl, so scope.updateHeight() certainly throws error. What about changing the value scope watches?

Comment: @sdfacre here are some updates to my test.  controller is showing updateHeight in my debugger in the before Each, but I am not hitting the tests.

Comment: what do you mean you are not hitting the tests? the test failed?

Comment: added this.timeout(15000) to get in to the test spec with the debugger.